# man path and 'man foo' vs. 'man -k foo'

Tags: man

I have a set of man pages in a non-standard location; however, the location is on my MANPATH (and I verified this with `man --path`).  When I do

```
man fst-infl
```

(where fst-infl has a man page in this non-standard location), it works: it brings up the man page for fst-infl.

But when I do

```
man -k fst-infl
```

I get

```
fst-infl: nothing appropriate
```

Same for `man -f` or `/usr/bin/apropos`.  All of these work fine for programs that are on the default MANPATH, e.g. `man -k fstab-decode`.

Why doesn't `man -k` look in the same place that plain `man` does?  More specifically, why doesn't it use MANPATH?

Comment: Have you tried using `mandb`?

Comment: Maybe the whatis database is not up to date or the makewhatis or the equivalent on your system wasn't called with the same MANPATH

Comment: Well, I can see that even if it was called (it's run by root, right?), makewhatis wouldn't know about the MANPATH that I set in my ~/.bashrc.  But what puzzles me is that 'man' by itself finds this man file just fine, but 'man -k' does not.

Comment: @ramonovski: No, and it doesn't seem to be installed on our system.

Comment: @MikeMaxwell In some systems it's called `man-db`

Comment: Unfortunately, neither mandb nor man-db seems to exist on our system.

Just to recap: 'man fst-infl' works fine, 'man -k fst-infl' does not.  Is 'man' searching a different db from 'man -k'?